# Is there an explanation of this part of code I have?

Tags: angular

```
 ngOnInit() {
 

    this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(({ agent }) => {
      if (agent) {
      console.log(agent);
      }
 }
```

I would like to understand where does agent come from because I didn't send agent in the url ?
May be I don't really understand the use of activatedRoute.data.suscribe

Comment: It's using ES6 [de-structuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). If the `activatedRoute` emits an object with property `agent` (for whatever reason) then it'll be used in the subscription callback.

Comment: Where does the the activatedRoute emit the object this is what I would like to know ?

Comment: you can find the params(agent) in the routing file or in the url of the window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular `ActivatedRoute` can accept an argument [`data`](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute#data) which could be used to send data. It would be resolved to an observable that could then be subscribed to in the component. And as stated in my comment, the snippet uses [de-structuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to get only the property `agent` from the object.

**Example**

Routing config

```js
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: "", component: DashboardComponent },
  {
    path: "editTodo",
    data: { agent: "Sample Agent", id: "1" },
    component: EditTodoComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes) ],
  declarations: ...,
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Component

```js
import { ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";

export class EditTodoComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private _actRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this._actRoute.data.subscribe({
      next: ({ agent }) => {
        if (agent) {
          console.log(agent);
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-route-navigation-optionalparams-3mttub?file=src/app/edit-todo/edit-todo.component.ts)

Comment: I am seing a property  resolve in my route compent is it the same ?

Comment: Yes. From the docs: _"An observable of the static and resolved data of this route."_

Comment: Hold on. I don't think so. The doc just says _"resolved data"_. Not a resolver.

Comment: Without seeing more of the code I don't think I can proceed any further.

Comment: I am seing a property  resolve in my route componentt is it the same ? This is what I am getting there : resolve : agentResolve .It seems that The agent service has been called in the route constructor to get the desired object

Comment: Now I think it's clear. If you've defined a resolver for the service, then yes any object assigned to the `resolve` property in route definition could be obtained from the `data` property of the `ActivatedRoute`.

Comment: In this case why using a resolver Instead of doing like you did above ?

Comment: I'm unfortunately not sure of it's advantages/disadvantages.